# How to get Xvfb display number

Tags: x11

How can I get the display number that used while running Xvfb? 
For example somebody run

./Xvfb :14

I need somehow to get the used display number 14.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13):

on a unix system, run

```
ps -ef|grep Xvfb
```

and it should list it there with the process

Comment: Thank Tom. Like this, I have a better overview over the processes.

Comment: does not show display information

Comment: @cosbor11 It does. For the output `ubuntu      5573    5564  0 11:47 pts/4    00:00:00 Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 -nolisten tcp -auth /tmp/xvfb-run.h9dPu7/Xauthority`, the `:99` is the display number.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways I can think of:

1. Look for the lock files, which will typically take the form \tmp.X*-lock, where * is the display number;
2. Look at the log files, typically \var\adm\xfvb.log, but might be anywhere.  There should be a line which says which display xfvb started listening to.