# How to configure VNC to view xvfb?

Tags: linux, vnc, xvfb

How do I configure my VNC server and viewer to remotely view an xvfb (X virtual frame buffer) on a Linux machine?

Comment: Any insight into why this got downvoted?

Comment: I voted to reopen this but it may in fact be a duplicate; the only difference is that this is asking specifically how to configure xvfb wit x11vnc whereas the other question is asking how to make an xvfb screen visible in a more general sense, and one of the answers suggests x11vnc.

Answer (score 1):

With root SSH access to a Linux/*nix server with a pre-existing shell script to open an xvfb desktop I want to view and interact with it over VNC.

On Fedora 22, do this by installing x11vnc: www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc
There was no yum or dnf package for x11vnc in Fedora 22, so I downloaded its C source code and installed it from the Shell:

A list of the required compiler and -devel packages for RedHat/Fedora and Ubuntu/Debian is at http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-build 
--but the list is incomplete!  You also may need:

**Remote SSH commands on the xvbf host**

```
yum install -y libXtst-devel
tar -xzvf x11vnc-0.9.13.tar.gz
./configure
make
make install
x11vnc --version
```

**Local vnc viewer commands**

```
yum install tigervnc
vncviewer -via root@myserver.com
ps -ef|grep Xvfb
```

[Get xvfb display number from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138131/how-to-get-xvfb-display-number)

Syntax includes a colon followed by the display number
myserver.com:0